# Trying to deploy aws-lambda-rss-feed-from-s3 to Lambda but keep gettig error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to set up a Lambda function in AWS that will trigger when a file is added or removed from a bucket and then write an RSS XML file back to the bucket. I found aws-lambda-rss-feed-from-s3.

I downloaded the files from git:
https://github.com/bwjjohnson/aws-lambda-rss-feed-from-s3

I then created the function in Lambda and the files are up there but I keep getting the error:
Error: Cannot find module 'rss'

I have to be missing a step. I'm not new to programming but I am new to Nodejs and Lambda.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: we need to clone the project, npm install and zip the project folder with node_modules and upload to lambda, you did that and still getting this error about missing rss module?

Comment: That's all I needed but I actually had a bigger problem... I had installed nodejs/NPM with NVM for Windows and I kept getting EPERM errors whenever I tried to install a module. I uninstalled everything, Installed nodejs/NPM with a DL right from the NPM site and now everything is working. Thanks for the guidance!